# How do application menus detect subcategories from .desktop files?

Tags: linux, desktop, gnu

GNOME Flashback's Application Menu, KDE Plasma Application Menu, etc. categorize apps into folders and subfolders like the traditional Windows Start menu. An app like MenuLibre can be used to edit those categories.

But how is the categories actually stored under the hood? How does MenuLibre and Application Menus know which categories a desktop file falls under?

Answer (score 1):

While looking for details to this question, I figured out the answer. The heirarchy of menus is described by XML files under `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/menus/`. This is in accordance with the Freedesktop [Desktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html).

The folders in which the shortcut appear will be chosen then by the `Categories`, `OnlyShowIn` and `NotShowIn` labels in the desktop file.